# Decomposition of tensor powers of the vector representation of $\frak{sl}_n$

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, young-tableaux

Let $V(\pi_1)$ be the usual vector/matrix representation of the Lie algebra $\frak{sl}_n$, for $n > 2$. A basic fact is the tensor product $V(\pi_1) \otimes V(\pi_1)$ decomposes as
$$
V(\pi_1) \otimes V(\pi_1) \simeq V_{2\pi_1} \oplus V_{\pi_2}.
$$
For higher tensor powers
$$
V(\pi_1)^{\otimes k}
$$
does there exist a formula to describe the decomposition into irreducibles? Thinking about this in Young diagram terms, it seems (more or less) clear that the $k^{\text{th}}$-tensor power will have summands whose diagrams contain $k$-boxes, and any Young diagram with $k$-boxes will appear. Hence the question reduces to the question of multiplicities.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The multiplicity of the Young diagram of shape $\lambda$ is the number of standard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$, which can be computed with the [hook length formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula). This can be deduced from [Schur-Weyl duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality).

Comment: Ah, of course, this is just Schur-Weyl duality!

Comment: Ah, that's probably a better thing to cite than Pieri. I'll edit.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! That's a nicer answer than I had hoped for

Comment: Is it easy to see why this is true?

Comment: Schur-Weyl duality says that $(\mathbb{C}^n)^{\otimes k} \cong \bigoplus_{|\lambda| = k} \text{Specht}_{\lambda} \boxtimes \text{Schur}_{\lambda}$ as an $S_k \times \text{GL}_n$ representation; the number of SYT of shape $\lambda$ is the dimension of $\text{Specht}_{\lambda}$.